# Java DataSource

Tags: java, database, datasource

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.connect.DBHelper.getConnection(DBHelper.java:15)
    at com.connect.DemoConnect.main(DemoConnect.java:13)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

what is the exception?
I am trying to use the dataSource..
this is my context.xml file..
I have added the xml file in meta-inf folder and added the ojdbc14.jar in tomcat lib folder..

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resource name="jdbc/mydatasource" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              username="YOUR_USERNAME" 
              password="YOUR_PASSWORD"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:[oracletrg/oracle]@10.180.168.112[:1521]/orcl?autoReconnect=true"
              maxActive="10" 
              maxIdle="4"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Have you added the relevant information in your `web.xml` as well?

Comment: Are you sure the context definition is used? Please add the code where the application loads it.

Comment: this might be too obvious but i hope the value for `url` attribute in the `resource` tag does not have the square brackets in it ...

Answer (score 0):

In your application server JNDI is defined and you are look up that then this error will come.
Please make sure your application server done have any jndi.

This exception is thrown when no initial context implementation can be created. The policy of how an initial context implementation is selected is described in the documentation of the InitialContext class.

This exception can be thrown during any interaction with the InitialContext, not only when the InitialContext is constructed. For example, the implementation of the initial context might lazily retrieve the context only when actual methods are invoked on it. The application should not have any dependency on when the existence of an initial context is determined.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html